# Output of a runspace factory in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I run this c# code in a asp.net application. I use c# to execute a powershell file. The powershell file search for a mailbox and delete a particular email.

The execution works, but when I try to get the output, I get a System.NullReferenceException'.

The problem is this line :

```
weboutput.InnerHtml += result.Members["Success"].ToString();
```

I tried various things to get some values :

```
pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
```

I added/removed : `|Out-String` in the powershell file.

I tried with result.properties, then I tried to cast the object and it outputed like this :

```
weboutput.InnerHtml += result.ToString();
```

It gives me the following :

```
Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Search.SearchMailboxResult
```

So here is the c# code :

```
        InitialSessionState initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });

        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
        runspace.Open();

        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        Command connectCommand = new Command(@"C:\DeleteMail.ps1");

        using (Runspace psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession))
        {
            // Open runspace. 
            psRunSpace.Open();

            //Iterate through each command and executes it. 
            foreach (var com in new Command[] { connectCommand })
            {
                var pipe = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline();
                pipe.Commands.Add(com);
                // Execute command and generate results and errors (if any). 
                //Collection<PSObject> results = pipe.Invoke();

                foreach (PSObject result in pipe.Invoke()) {
                weboutput.InnerHtml += result.Members["Success"].ToString();
                }

                var error = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();

            }
            // Close the runspace. 
            psRunSpace.Close();
        }
    }
```

Here is the powershell file.

```
Import-Module MsOnline

$AdminUsername = "admin@domain.com"

$AdminPassword = "SuperSecret!111"

$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $AdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force

$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminUsername,$SecurePassword

Connect-MSOLService -Credential $cred

$exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $cred -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $exchangeSession –DisableNameChecking

Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {Name -eq "bigboss"} | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery "me@domain.com Subject:'test'" -DeleteContent -Force | Out-String
```

Finally here is the output when I run the powershell file alone.

```
RunspaceId       : random #
Identity         : bigboss
TargetMailbox    : 
Success          : True
TargetFolder     : 
ResultItemsCount : 1
ResultItemsSize  : 124 KB (124 kilobytes)
```

How can I get the output of the file and/or how can I parse the values of the PSObject ?

Comment: `"Succes"` -> `"Success"`

Comment: @PeSerAl it was a typo, the original code is indedd "Success"

Comment: Two options to consider.
1. turn your powershell script into a function that returns a boolean.  you'd invoke 2 commands, the first being the creation of the function, the second being the execution of the function.
2. you could wrap your last line in the script with an IF statement and either set a variable to True/False, or simply place $TRUE or $FALSE on the pipeline.

I try to leave as much as i can in the powershell session and only pull back to .NET what i actually want...like a boolean value in your case.